# When to use Lazy translation in Django

Tags: django

When are lazy translated string objects required in Django?
From the documentation they say option values like verbose_name and help_text are required to be lazy translated. What about other options like related_name and through?
What is the purpose of lazy translating the options verbose_name and help_text?

What is the significance of lazy translation for fields being class-level attributes?

> These functions store a lazy reference to the string – not the actual translation. The translation itself will be done when the string is used in a string context, such as in template rendering.

> This is essential when calls to these functions are located in code paths that are executed at module load time.

> This is something that can easily happen when defining models, forms and model forms, because Django implements these such that their **fields** are actually **class-level attributes**. For that reason, make sure to use lazy translations in the following cases:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Subscription')

class MyThing(models.Model):
    kind = models.ForeignKey(
        ThingKind,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='kinds',
        verbose_name=_('kind'),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question says: you are not unterstand the laziness of python.

lazy translation is only promise to give you somewhen the string with really translated text. But if you don't need it, it not happens.

We have a much Advantages, if we create a lazy object:

- nothing happens, we have created only the promise.
- we can work with lazy object like with normal object.
- only if we really need it - we can resolve the promise.
- if you works correct with lazy objects - really increase speed of your synchron code.

We have disadvantages:

- nothing happens, you can not see or debug the result of promise before promise is resolved.
- additional lazy wrapper have own costs: memory and delay if you need the result.
- 90% of python developers don't understand it. They receive only problem with lazy objects.

Generator is the best example - it is perfect and fast. most programmers don't use generators: famous curio or asyncio completely forgotten about lazyness.

I don't like how work lazy translation in django, that's why i create my own library Django-tof (Translation-On-Fly).
https://github.com/wP-soft-GmbH/django-tof

Now the answer on the question:

You are should use lazy translation if:

1. You have static text, but not always you are need translation of this text. 99 % in Django
2. You have static text, you need translation of this text in 100%, but the translations comes with delay. For example: Object have init with translated text before load of translations block. Rare elements which should to do something on project start. For example: custom Testrunner and messages about process. 0.01% in Django.
3. if you are not worried about the speed/memory consumption of your function. 99.99% in python.